# Playing sounds very fast with Soundpool

Tags: java, android, soundpool, mixing

I am creating an app that requires a sound or sounds to potentially be played every ~25ms.  (300beats per minute with potentially 8 "plays" per beat)

At first I used SoundPool to accomplish this.  I have 3 threads.  One is updating the SurfaceView animation, one is updating the time using System.nanoTime(), and the other is playing the sounds (mp3s) using Soundpool.

This works, but seems to be using a lot of processor power as anytime a background process runs such as the WiFi rescanning, or GC, it starts skipping beats here and there, which is unacceptable.

I am looking for an alternative solution.  I've looked at mixing and also the JET engine.

The JET engine doesn't seem like a solution as it only uses MIDIs.  My app requires high-quality sounds (recordings from actual instruments).  (correct me if I'm wrong on midi not being high quality)

Mixing seems very complicated with Android as it seems first you must get the raw sound (takes up a lot of memory) and also create "silence" in between sounds.  I am not sure if this is the most elegant solution as my app will have variable speed (bpm) controlled by the user.

If anyone is experienced in this area, I would GREATLY appreciate any advice.

Thank you